# Build-list within build-list Scheme/DrRacket

Tags: list, scheme, racket

Trying to make a list  that has n elements with each of those lists having r elements. i.e.
`(function 2 3)` would be `(list (list 0 0 0)(list 0 1 2))`. And those elements are made by multiplying the nth element by the rth element starting at 0. This is my code:

```
(define (nr nc)     
  (build-list nr (lambda (x) 
                   (build-list nc (lambda (x) (* x 1))))))
```

so I have `(function 2 3)` coming out to `(list (list 0 1 2)(list 0 1 2))` and I can't figure out how to multiply the first list by 0, the second by 1, third by 2, and so on.

Comment: what would (function 3 3) be? ((0 0 0) (0 1 2) (0 2 4))?

Comment: That would be (list (list 0 0 0)(list 0 1 2)(list 0 2 4)) so yes youre right

Answer (score 1):

You were close:

```
(define (build nr nc)     
  (build-list nr (lambda (r) 
                   (build-list nc (lambda (c) (* r c))))))

> (build 2 3)
'((0 0 0) (0 1 2))

> (build 3 3)
'((0 0 0) (0 1 2) (0 2 4))
```

An alternative:

```
(define (build2 nr nc)
  (for/list ([r nr])
    (for/list ([c nc])
      (* r c))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(define (range n)
  (define (range-iter i accum)
    (if (= i 0) (cons 0 accum)
        (range-iter (- i 1) (cons i accum))))
  (range-iter (- n 1) `()))

(define (nested-list n r)
  (map 
   (lambda (multiplier) 
     (map 
      (lambda (cell) (* cell multiplier)) 
      (range r))) 
   (range n)))
```

Comment: unfortunately I have to use build-list

Comment: Looking at the docs, `build-list` is basically `map` on `range`. It's almost trivial to convert from my answer to `build-list`. Looking at your attempt in the question, the way to make it work is to put the multiplication in the 'outer' `build-list` and make the 'inner' `build-list` just make homogenous ranges.

Comment: So putting it in the outer build-list, how do I multiply the first list by 0 and so on

Comment: the inner `build-list` will create the list ((0 ... n-1) (0 ... n-1) ... (0 ... n-1)). You want to multiply every element in the first sublist by 0, every element in the second sublist by 1, etc. To apply a function to every element in a list, you use `map`. I hope you can figure it out from here.

Comment: Bah, actually, disregard what I said. You did have the right approach to the problem originally. Your problem is that `x` in the innermost lambda is shadowing `x` in the outer lambda. If you change the name for one of them, it should work.

Comment: err, and you'll have to do `(* x y)` rather than `(* x 1)` (assuming you name the other variable y)